# Android: how to create list background similar to one in gmail app?

Tags: android

In the attached screenshot of the Gmail app, the ListView's background seems to have a vertical gradient on the right side of the list to separate from the neighboring View.

I know I can define a GradientDrawable in xml, but how can I use this to draw a gradient as the background of one side of the list, while drawing the rest of the list's background as light grey?

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#DDDDDD"
      android:endColor="#CCCCCC"
      android:angle="0" />
</shape>
```

[image]

Comment: I just posted solution for your problem. That will behave exactly same as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can setup the drawable to be 95% light grey, with the gradient on the right half, using the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#DDDDDD"
      android:centerColor="#DDDDDD"
      android:endColor="#CCCCCC"
      android:centerX=".95"
      android:centerY=".95"
      android:angle="0" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just assign your the cutsom drawable you created as the background attribute of your ListView item.  You can do this in the XML layout you are using to define your list element.

As an example, I use this layout (list_item.xml) to define a custom layout for my list items (and assign a gradient as a background):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_gray_gradient"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

...
```

Comment: sizing of the gradient won't be right.  the gradient will occur along the entire width of the listview, as opposed to only the along the right side.

Comment: ...understood, added another answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a drawable, and place it to the right of your the Layout containing your list items.  So, your gradient is a separate component in your view, that sperated your ListView for the view on the right.

Something like this pseudo-code

```
<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="horizontal"

   <ListView

   />

   <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_drawable"
   >


>
```

Comment: I think the gradient should be part of the background of the list so that the list divider lines draw on top of the gradient.  If I place it to the right of the list, the individual list items would end prior to the gradient beginning.

Comment: Not necessarily, you can use a negative alignment attribute (ie. android:layout_marginRight="-2dp" to align it as you want;

Comment: ah, that's a reasonable idea.  I just found a solution which I am adding as an answer, it seems a little cleaner.

Comment: Cool, that seems like a reasonable answer too.  Glad you found your solution!

Answer (score 0):

First Create this `drawable` : **(drawable/list_gray_gradient.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- This is the line -->
<item>
      <shape>
            <solid android:color="#CCCCCC" />
      </shape>
</item>
<!-- This is the main color -->
<item android:right="10dp">
     <shape>
           <solid android:color="#DDDDDD" />
     </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

And then just use this to your `list item layout`: **(layout/list_item.xml)**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:background="@drawable/list_gray_gradient" >
</RelativeLayout>
```